# Have problem understanding this assembly code from CS:APP

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm reading CS:APP on Chapter 3 about assembly code. There is a practice problem like this:
[image]

[image]

In the solution it tells me that

> The compiler determines that pointer p always points to x, and hence the
> expression (*p)+=5 simply increments x. It combines this incrementing by
> 5 with the increment of y, via the leaq instruction of line 7.

And `leaq 5(%rbx,%rcx),%rcx`means`Compute y += x + 5`
So I rewrite the C code function according the assembly code like this:

```c
short dw_loop (short x)
{
    short y = x / 9;
    short *p = &x;
    short n = 4 * x;
    do
    {
        y += 5 + x;
        n -= 2;
    } while (n > 0);
    return y;
};
```

Obviously the result will be different from the original function. So how can I understand that assembly code? I don't know why `x+=y;(*p)+=5` can be translated as`y+=5+x`.

Comment: It should be x += y + 5. You got it the wrong way around.

Comment: The assembly code shown doesn't match the C code. In the loop, it decrements n by 1 instead of 2. It doesn't return a value.  And you're right—it is changing y instead of x.

Comment: See the duplicate.  This is a badly written question in the book; some of the instructions in the supposed assembly output don't even exist (`idivq` with two operands).  It is probably not worth trying to understand.  That particular edition has exercises where the supposed compiler output is not from the compiler at all, but just some nonsense that the problem author made up.  (The problems were written by a third party hired by the publisher and the book's main authors have disclaimed responsibility; don't blame them.)